# Eigendecomposition of $ \boldsymbol{I}_p - \boldsymbol{p}\boldsymbol{p}^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Let be $\boldsymbol{p}$ a $n$-dimensional real vector ($p_i \geq 0, \sum p_i =1$).
Is there a general analytical solution for, or a simple way to compute the eigendecomposition 
$ \boldsymbol{I}_p - \boldsymbol{p}\boldsymbol{p}^T = \boldsymbol{U \Lambda U^T}$,
where $ \boldsymbol{I}_p$ is a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with entries $p_i$ on the diagonal?

---

The multinomial distribution can be approximated by the multivariate normal distribution. Let be $\boldsymbol{p}$ the $n$-dim probability vector of the multinomial and $k$ the number of trials. Then the mean vector of the approximating multivariate normal distribution is $k\boldsymbol{p}=(kp_1,kp_2,...,kp_n)$. Its covariance matrix is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with diagonal elements $kp_i(1−p_i), i=1,2...,n$ and off-diagonal elements $−kp_ip_j, i\neq j$. 
Hence, the term $ k (\boldsymbol{I}_p - \boldsymbol{p}\boldsymbol{p}^T)$.
Now its eigendecomposition $\boldsymbol{U \Lambda U^T}$ is going to give $\boldsymbol{Y}=\sqrt{k \boldsymbol{\Lambda}} \boldsymbol{ U X}$, where $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\boldsymbol{I})$ is a column vector of $n$ standard normal RV's, i.e. $n$ RVs $Y_i=\sqrt{k\lambda_i} \sum_{j=1}^n u_{i,j} X_j$ with the desired covariance. 
I believe the $u_{i,j}$ have been analytically determined for this multinomial-normal relation.

Comment: Can you compute the determinant, to start with? The only similar formula I know is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1189925/8157), but the similarity may be only psychological, due to the fact that your $\mathbf{I}_p$ "looks like" the identity...

Comment: Thx - looked into it. This gave me the idea to look for the determination of eigenvalues of a sum of two matrices.  It would appear this is not a straightforward operation. I'll add to my post a bit more background info of how I came up with my stated problem. The problem originates from an elementary relationship to the Gaussian, which is reason enough for me to believe that someone has already solved it.

Comment: We can compute the determinat by a matrix determinant lemma $\det (I_p+pp^\top) = (1+p^\top I_p^{-1}p) \det I_p =(1+p^T\mathbf 1)\prod_i p_i=(1+\sum_i p_i) \prod_i p_i$, where $\mathbf 1=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: How handy! Didn't know this one. Thx a lot Jochen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can compute $p^T \mathbf 1 = 1$ and $I_p \mathbf 1 =p$, giving that $\mathbf 1$ is in the kernel. I don't know how to reconcile my observation with @Jochen's though, in the case that all $p_i$ are nonzero.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052997/81360) is relevant

Comment: Oh you need to replace every $+$ with $-$ to correct their application of the matrix determinant lemma.

Comment: Thx for the remark @Dustan. That would actually result in 
$det(I_p - p p^T) = (1-1) \prod_i p_i$.